# How to use flowOn and launchIn methods to collect from a Kotlin SharedFlow in a test

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-testing, kotlin-flow

Consider the following test.  `test shared flow A` will pass, but `test shared flow B` will fail.

I was under the impression that these were equivalent statements.

Why does `test shared flow B` fail?
Is there a way to make it pass, while still using the `launchIn` method?

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableSharedFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flowOn
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.launchIn
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.onEach
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.UnconfinedTestDispatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runTest
import org.junit.Test

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class SomethingTest {

    @Test
    fun `test shared flow A`() = runTest {
        val flow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
        val items = mutableListOf<Int>()
        val job = launch(UnconfinedTestDispatcher()) {
            flow.collect {
                items.add(it)
            }
        }
        flow.emit(1)
        assert(items.size == 1)
        job.cancel()
    }

    @Test
    fun `test shared flow B`() = runTest {
        val flow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
        val items = mutableListOf<Int>()
        val job = flow.onEach { items.add(it) }
            .flowOn(UnconfinedTestDispatcher())
            .launchIn(this)
        flow.emit(1)
        assert(items.size == 1)
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `test shared flow A` nor `test shared flow B` is guaranteed to pass because neither test waits for `launch` to complete before `assert`.

`test shared flow A` happens to pass, and will fail if you slightly delay adding an item.

> Is there a way to make it pass, while still using the launchIn method?

Adding `advanceUntilIdle()` will pass `test shared flow B`.

```kotlin
@Test
fun `test shared flow B`() = runTest {
    val flow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
    val items = mutableListOf<Int>()
    val job = flow.onEach { items.add(it) }
        .flowOn(UnconfinedTestDispatcher())
        .launchIn(this)
    advanceUntilIdle()
    flow.emit(1)
    assert(items.size == 1)
    job.cancel()
}
```